# Getting jars from scope provided maven web project

Tags: java, maven, web-applications

I'm currently developing a Java webapp using maven for building (I'm not to experienced with mvn yet). For my scenario the application requires the provided scope. 
Now how would I 'extract' the jars defined in the pom file so that I could copy them to my Tomcat lib folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `maven-dependency-plugin`'s `copy-dependencies` goal to copy the dependency jars with `provided` scope to a specific directory

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <includeScope>provided</includeScope>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/providedDependencies</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```