# How to get specific version dependencies jars from maven artifactory repository who has "Provided" scope

Tags: maven, maven-2, tomcat7, maven-3, tomcat8

Is it possible to get specific version dependencies jars from maven artifactory repository who has "Provided" scope after the build.Due to so many webapps and most of them having common dependencies, thought of making all dependencies as "Provided" (So that WEB-INF/lib would be empty) and getting all "provided" jars of specific version from the artifactory repository during deployment (Very first step of deployment is copying the jars in to Tomcat common lib followed by war deployment).If possible please help me by giving model script to do the copy from repository to tomcat common lib before deployment.

Assume app having 3 webapp (webapp1,webapp2 and webapp3) and all using abc1.jar,abc2.jar,abc3.jar.each webapp classloader loading all these 3 for each war to deploy.Instead making them as provided and keeping 3 jars in Tomcat common lib would be appropriate i feel.Now my question is after the maven build, can i get provided jars from repository to copy them from repository to tomcat lib using shell script

### Sample pom.xml (Without provided scope)

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.group.groupid
    mSampleJDBCTempPrj
    war
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    mSampleJDBCTempPrj Maven Webapp
    http://maven.apache.org
    
        
            org.springframework
            spring-context
            3.1.1.RELEASE
        
        
            cglib
            cglib
            2.2.2

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>mSampleJDBCTempPrj</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- <includeScope>provided</includeScope> -->
                        <outputDirectory>/Users/venugopal/Documents/providedDependencies</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Your question make no sense. You should rewrite it to explain: what you want to do, why, what you have tried, what went wrong and what you expect. It's impossible to help you otherwise.

Comment: The concept that you are using for managing multiple dependencies accross the applications is not appropriate, you should use parent pom. and afaik maven will fetch all jars, if it is in "provided" scope it won't be included in your final build. :) :) for further details read the maven documentation.. :) https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html

Comment: Please research Maven scopes and then return here if you still have a question

Comment: Assume app having 3 webapp (webapp1,webapp2 and webapp3) and all using abc1.jar,abc2.jar,abc3.jar.each webapp classloader loading all these 3 for each war to deploy.Instead making them as provided and keeping 3 jars in Tomcat common lib would be appropriate i feel.Now my question is after the maven build, can i get provided jars from repository to copy them from repository to tomcat lib using shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the idea is, to create an archive, which contains the jars, that are marked with the scope *provided* in the `pom.xml`. So if multiple web-apps use these same jars, they can be deployed to the central place in the wen container provider (Tomcat / Jetty / JBoss / etc).

*For as far as I know* there is no option in Maven to create an archive, for these provided dependencies. Or some other way to extract them easily from the Maven repository.

*A question rises* Why would you do so? Many projects move these days to Docker or similar solutions. Which deploy just one web-app in one container. So no need for the complexity of searching for commin libraries and placing them upfront on the web container. Etc etc.

*Another question* Why add complexity. An easier set-up is to add all depended jars to the web-app. As disk space and network speed / capacity, is most of the time not an issue.

Seems the answer [Getting jars from scope provided maven web project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516202/getting-jars-from-scope-provided-maven-web-project?rq=1) is already provided

**TIP** The above sample, shows the usage of the `maven-dependency-plugin`. It is configured to run during the phase *package* (`<phase>package</phase>`).
Use `mvn clean package`, to let it do it's task.

The `pom.xml` needed a few small modifications:

- This is just a small pom.xml, so `package` should be `pom`, as there is no web-app content, Java classes, configuration etc.
- In `build`, the `finalName` is not needed.
- Updated dependency `postgresql` it's `scope` with value *provided*, so at least one dependency is resolved, by the plug-in
- Removed `pluginManagement` which should be used in parent-pom cases, not here. Here it just hides the plug-in. In cases where it is used, the parent-pom defines the plugin configuration for multiple Maven projects. All projects which use the same parent-pom, can include a plugin, with the same version number and configuration, as given in the parent-pom.

**Addition**

The corrected `pom.xml`, from the question:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.group.groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>mSampleJDBCTempPrj</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mSampleJDBCTempPrj Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeScope>provided</includeScope>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/providedDependencies</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks..I totally agree that one webapp per container.It would take time to switch our webapps to that environment.Looking for the solution all provided jars can be moved to specific folder in maven artifactory repository itself.Tried this but no use.
       <goals>
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>
         ${project.build.directory}/lib
        </outputDirectory>

Comment: I know that provided scope dependencies cant be taken @Runtime.But there may be ways to get them during build time.Any ways to move provided dependency jars to some folder in artifactory repository? If this happens , same folder can be kept under Tomcat to use as common lib

Comment: It is not a good idee to install an additional folder in Artifactory, which contain the same jars, as somewhere else in the Artifactory (the normal location). Better to create something that extracts the _provided_ jars so the can be installed on the web container (Tomcat) that need them.

Comment: There is the difference...folder can be created during build time and same can be taken under TOmcat s common lib during deployment.i.e commonlib get created first followed by webapp war deployment.so that deployment doesnt take much time.Imgine if 200 jars are there and reading pom.xml to get list of jars and taking each jar  from repective location from artifactory and copying one by one to tomcat/commonlib...i feel it impacts deployment time and more burden.

Comment: See updated answer for getting all the _provided_ jars. Test if it would work for your situation.

Comment: I copied that and tried same in one of my webapp...after mvn clean install command mentioned folder is not generated under my webapp root directory..Do i need to do anything else

Comment: The plugin will run during the <phase>package</phase>, so you'll need to call `mvn clean package`, here clean in optional.

Comment: NOt working for me, verified in my webapp folder folder with provided jars are not shown.given mvn clean package and phase showing as package also

Comment: The _provided_ depencies are not added to the webapp directory. They are placed in a seperate directory `target/providedDependencies`.

Comment: Verified there also already , but not shown.here i m putting what i have done.I have 9 webapps and added plugin for copying to providedDependencies directory (Copied from suggested link) in one of the webapp to check.verified after mvn clean package command in target folder but providedDependencies directory not get created

Comment: You'll need to add the `maven-dependency-plugin` configuration to a existing `pom.xml`. This could be one of the projects (just to test it). And then run the `mvn clean package`, on that package.

Comment: In case you have a super-pom (parent-pom) which is used by all the web-app projects, you could add the configuration there. Place it in a Maven profile, so it only gets executed, when Maven is executed with the profile enabled.

Comment: pLease go through my sample pom.xml and correct the same if anything required.It is not working though it is not provided scope.If that works thought of making all dependencies with provided scope.PLease help me